# Isoelastic Demands

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics

I have a very simple question:

I'm studying Acemoglu's book the horizontal innovation paradigm of endogenous growth.

Here, the conditional demand function for the machine variety $\upsilon$, i.e., $x(\upsilon,t)$ is given by $[13.6]$, and the book says that it is isoelastic. Does this mean that the elasticity of substitution between any pair of machines is constant? Does this mean that after a change in the relative price of a machine $\upsilon$ with respect to $\upsilon'$, for any $\upsilon \neq \upsilon'$ the ratio between $\upsilon$ and $\upsilon'$ changes at a constant rate regardless of the initial quantity of the pair of machines?
Finally, since machines are manufactured in monopolistic competition, does the isoelastic shape of $[13.6]$ ensure constant mark-up over the marginal cost?

[image]

Further info:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isoelastic here means both the elasticity of demand to its own price and the elasticity of substitution are constant. The former is obvious given $x(v, t)=p^{x}(v, t)^{-1 / \beta} L$ and thus the markup is also a constant. The latter can be also shown directly by $\frac{x\left(v_{1}\right)}{x\left(v_{2}\right)}=\left(\frac{p\left(v_{1}\right)}{p\left(v_{2}\right)}\right)^{-1 / \beta} $.